# Highcharts display priority of overlapping labels

Tags: highcharts

When data labels overlap in Highcharts, only one data label is displayed. This seems to be handled randomly. See fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/lamarant/rmxLd1d4/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Label Test'
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'line',
            data: [ 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 50],
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
              color: 'blue',
              zIndex: 10
            },
            zIndex: 10
        },
        {
            type: 'line',
            data: [ 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 49],
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
              color: 'red',
              zIndex: 10
            },
            zIndex: 20
        }]
    });
});
```

Notice that the first data label displayed in the chart is from the second series while the rest are from the first series.

I tried setting the priority of the label display using zIndex in both **series** and **series.dataLabel** with no luck.

Is there any way to set it so that a designated series always takes priority when Highcharts determines which label to display?

Comment: You can enable all datalabels by option [allowOverlap](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.allowOverlap) as true. Then apply workaround like here: - http://jsfiddle.net/menXU/1/
- http://jsfiddle.net/menXU/6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible fix is supplying a `labelrank` for each point, which is used to evaluate their sorting order. If you supply this rank for each point in a series, that series should be considered "above" series without such a rank (or with a lower rank integer value).

In code, manually for each point:

```
series: [{
    data: [ 
        { y: 11, labelrank: 1 }, 
        { y:11, labelrank: 1 } 
        // ...
    ],
    // ...
}]
```

In code, using the callback function ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rmxLd1d4/3/)):

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    // Options ...
}, function() {
    var mySeriesIndex = 1;

    // For each point in the preferred series
    for(i = 0; i < this.series[mySeriesIndex].points.length; i++)
        // Set a labelrank
        this.series[mySeriesIndex].points[i].labelrank = 1;
});
```

My current take on the issue itself is this:

With the current implementation of the overlap logic it seems to me that this is a  bit of an unintended behavior. The source code uses `Array.sort` in a way that shifts the positions of the point labels, since `Array.sort` is not guaranteed to be stable (same-value items wont retain their original order).

If you check your example in Firefox it should work as intended (their implementation of `Array.sort` is different), while in Chrome it doesn't (not stable). You could hope that this little feature is fixed.

Comment: If someone has some more insight into this (intended, unintended?) I'd love to hear it! Also to confirm/correct my problem hypothesis.

Comment: setting labelrank for each data point seems to work. I set labelrank for each data point in the preferred series and they are all displaying. thank you!

Comment: ps: IMO a "labelrank" property for each series would be make sense with default rank being the order that each series is added to the chart.